# Snakemake: import local python module from a Python script in Singularity

Tags: python, snakemake, singularity-container

I'm rather new to Snakemake, and I'm wondering if it is possible to import a local python module from another script when using the singularity environment. Following [the instruction](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html), I set the directory as the following:

[image: directory]

and wrote `import utils` in the `script.py`.

The workflow runs without error when I used `--use-conda` but not `--use-singularity`, but with `--use-singularity` (using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/yfukai/docker-gpu-conda)), it failed with an error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

I'm now wondering if there would be any way to import a local file from scripts. I checked the [doc](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-import-some-helper-functions-from-another-python-file-is-that-possible) but it seems to be about importing from Snakefile. Could anyone help me?

The OS is `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)`, and I'm using `Snakemake 6.5.1` with `Python 3.9.5`.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example so that I can try to help you? Does it run when you don't import `utils.py` with `--use-singularity`?

Comment: Hi thanks @CorneliusRoemer for your comment! I made a minimal (and hopefully reproducible) example workflow : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pa514fQp8AQhYa4oSZsIFy7f7YCeioTC/view?usp=sharing
Interestingly, it runs with `snakemake --cores 1 --use-conda --use-singularity --conda-frontend=conda` and `snakemake --directory=~/somedir/ --cores 1 --use-conda --conda-frontend=conda` but not with `snakemake --directory=~/somedir/ --cores 1 --use-conda --use-singularity --conda-frontend=conda` . (And when I remove `utils.py` dependency, it also runs.)

Comment: Maybe this is just a bug of snakemake, I will try to make an issue in the repo.